# I am getting error in verilog in modelsim "endmodule"

Tags: verilog

I am trying to arbiter in verilog. But i am getting errors : `"endmodule"`

This is my code:

```
module rr_arbiter (
clk, // positive edge trigger
reset,  // negative edge trigger
req,grant,
priority, priority_req);

input clk, reset;
input [3:0]req;
input priority;
input [1:0] priority_req;

output [3:0] grant; 
integer i;
always@(posedge clk) begin

if (reset) begin
//all grant = 0
for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
grant[i] = 0; //reset
end

else
if(priority == 0)begin
//0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3 ....
for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
if(req[i] == 0)
grant[0] <= req[i];
else if(req[i] == 1)
grant[1] <= req[i];
else if(req[i] == 2)
grant[2] <= req[i];
else if(req[i] == 3)
grant[3] <= req[i];
end

if(priority == 1)begin
if (reset) begin
//all grant = 0
for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
grant[i] = 0; //reset
end

if(priority_req==0)begin //0
//counter : 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 3 ..
for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
if(req[i] == 0)
grant[0] <= req[i];
grant[1] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 1)
grant[2] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 2)
grant[3] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 3)
grant[0] <= req[i];
end

else if(priority_req==1)begin
//counter : 0 1 1 2 3 0 1 1 2 3 ..
for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
if(req[i] == 0)
grant[0] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 1)
grant[1] <= req[i];
grant[2] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 2)
grant[3] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 3)
grant[0] <= req[i];
end
else if(priority_req==2)begin
//counter : 0 1 2 2 3 0 1 2 2 3 ..
for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
if(req[i] == 0)
grant[0] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 1)
grant[1] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 2)
grant[2] <= req[i];
grant[3] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 3)
grant[0] <= req[i];
end

else if(priority_req==3)begin
//counter : 0 1 2 3 3 0 1 2 3 3 ..
for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
if(req[i] == 0)
grant[0] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 1)
grant[1] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 2)
grant[2] <= req[i];
if(req[i] == 3)
grant[3] <= req[i];
grant[0] <= req[i];
end

else if(priority_req>3)begin
for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
grant[i] = 0;
end
end  

endmodule
```

I want make round robin priority arbiter module.

I'm not sure if I wrote the wrong end of the stick. I am concerned if the problem is that if there is a problem with the quotation or whether it should be re-coded again from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Many syntax errors in Verilog code point to the line just after the problem. The practice of proper code indentation with any editor having a Verilog mode will show that you have missed an `end` before the `endmodule`.

Other errors: grant needs to be defined as a `reg`. Also you have a lot of code with `req[i] == 3`. But req[i] is a single bit. Consider looking at the `casez` statement.